# Javascript - stats.js (Hi-Res stats from MrDoob) - how to get current FPS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, statistics

So there is great [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js) and I need it to give me its current FPS value. How to do such thig?

So I try

```
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.left = '0px';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
$('body').append(stats.domElement );
setInterval( function () { stats.update();}, 1000 / 60 );
setInterval(function () { if(stats._fps <= 50){
// Do stuff for slow guys
    }}, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Stats](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/blob/master/src/Stats.js) object only has two public properties: `domElement` and `update()`.

To retrieve the FPS, you would have to add a `getFPS` function to the object returned by the Status constructor, like this:

```
return {
    domElement: _container,
    getFPS: function () {
        return _fps;
    },
    update: function () {
        // ...
    }
};
```

That way, you can retrieve the FPS value using `stats.getFPS()`.