# Three.js - Get FPS rate of the video

Tags: three.js, frame-rate

I can't find it anywhere.

Is there a method in Three.js to get the current FPS value of the playing video?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript - stats.js (Hi-Res stats from MrDoob) - how to get current FPS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531100/javascript-stats-js-hi-res-stats-from-mrdoob-how-to-get-current-fps)

Comment: video really has nothing to do with either three.js or webgl. It's solely an HTML5 thing. As such AFAICT [there is no way to get the FPS for a video](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420724/how-to-determine-the-intended-frame-rate-on-an-html-video-element). Unless I mis-understood your question